# xamarin.ios service extension. failed to modify push notification

Tags: ios, notifications, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, apple-push-notifications

I have a problem using service extension with xamarin ios (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications/).

I performed the following steps:

1. created ios app for xamarin forms (bundle id: com.myprogram.test)
2. created service extension project (bundle id: com.myprogram.testnotificationservice)
3. configured app id from step one to receive push notification (for app id from step2 this feature is disabled)
4. referenced extension project from the main one (got the following string in csproj file:

   ```
   <ProjectReference Include="..\MyServiceExtension.csproj">
   <Project>{....}</Project>
   <Name>MyServiceExtension</Name>
   <IsAppExtension>true</IsAppExtension>
   <IsWatchApp>false</IsWatchApp>
   </ProjectReference>
   ```

after that I have deployed app to the device and tried to send test push notification (mutable-content was set to 1)

but notification extension has failed to execute :-( Any ideas what I have to check?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any luck with this? I've been trying to get this working today and am seeing the same behaviour.

Comment: If it helps, I managed to get mine working using a release build. Debug builds did not seem to be picking up the extension

Comment: no luck for now unfortunately. was trying both release and debug modes. the same result :-(

Comment: Whats your deployment target? Remember if you are targeting a specific architecture, this should be reflected in the info.plist of your notification extension

Comment: nope, nothing special. Deployment target is iphone (using iphone 6s).